# How to find all filenames with given extension

Tags: linux, unix, find

I need to find all `.pem` files on my system. Would the following do this?

```
sudo find / -type f -name *.pem
```

If not, how would I write a find command to find every file of the sort?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're on the right track -- you just need to quote the pattern so that it gets interpreted by `find` and not by your shell:

```
sudo find / -type f -name '*.pem'
```

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: /me holsters the pistols ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Using `find /` will normally be very slow.  Using `locate` is much faster but somewhat imprecise because it doesn't support anything more complex than substring matching.  A directory called `.pembroke` will be found and returned by locate along with every file inside it.

A combination of `locate` and `grep`, however, has speed *and* precision.  Conveniently, it also does not require `sudo`.

```
locate .pem | grep "\.pem$"
```

The downside?  The database `locate` uses is normally only updated once per day so any recent changes (additions, deletions, name changes, etc.) will not be found.

Comment: locate is much faster than find

Answer (score 1):

Almost!

```
sudo find / -type f -name \*.pem
```

or

```
sudo find / -type f -name "*.pem"
```

otherwise the shell will interpret the * instead of find.

Comment: \\* is a bit depended on the shell and the flavor of Unix. (Will work as intended on most systems though.) The quoted version will always work as far as I know.

Comment: That's funny. Had to write \\\* to escape the escape. Very appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

...or if mlocate runs on your computer and you don't need the most actual data use locate command

```
locate *.pam
```

It's faster becouse it finds files in previously created database; not on whole system.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo find / | grep .pam
```

Think that should work.